# SQL Exclude Zero from Case Column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query inserting values into a table and am using CASE to determine the value for each row. I was wondering if it is possible at the end of it to then exclude null or zero from the calculated column?

```
   CASE
       WHEN Value = 0 THEN Value2
       WHEN Value2 < Value1 THEN Value3
       WHEN Value2 > Value1 THEN Value4
   END AS Final_Value
```

This produces a few hundred thousand rows, of which a good few thousand are now zero or null. Can I exclude these in the same piece of code?

Thanks

Comment: you can avoid it in the end of query like   Where Final_Value <> 0

Comment: You want to exclude 0 but you are checking that in a condition... so your first WHEN is unnecessary, no? If you use a where clause, it will be removed from the entire dataset... which is probably what you want

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `where` clause:

```
select 
   ...
 , case 
  when value = 0
   then value2
  when value2 < value1
   then value3
  when value2 > value1
   then value4
  end as final_value
from  ...
where case
       when value = 0 then value2
       when value2 < value1 then value3
       when value2 > value1 then value4
   end <> 0
```

Comment: or value is not null +1 for speed

Comment: @scsimon `null <> 0` returns `null`, so it would be excluded. rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HON14029

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @jarlh If the deterministic expression in the `where` is the same expression as in the `select` it makes no difference.

Comment: @SqlZim, when MySQL or SQL Server, or both? (I'd go with a derived table anyway, to avoid typing the same case twice...)

Answer (score 0):

0 or null values can be avoided in the end of query like

```
SELECT  
ACCGRPID, 
LOCID, 
USERID4, 
LOBNAME, 
REINSTYPE, 
INCEPTDATE, 
EXPIREDATE, 
Latitude, 
Longitude, 
CountryRMSCode, 
StreetAddress, 
CityName, 
ACCGRPNUM, 
ACCGRPNAME,    
CASE
   WHEN Value = 0 THEN Value2
   WHEN Value2 < Value1 THEN Value3
   WHEN Value2 > Value1 THEN Value4
END AS Final_Value
FROM  <table_name>
WHERE Final_Value <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ;WITH CTE AS (
       select
          ACCGRPID, 
          LOCID, 
          USERID4, 
          LOBNAME, 
          REINSTYPE, 
          INCEPTDATE, 
          EXPIREDATE, 
          Latitude, 
          Longitude, 
          CountryRMSCode, 
          StreetAddress, 
          CityName, 
          ACCGRPNUM, 
          ACCGRPNAME,    
          CASE
                 WHEN Value = 0 THEN Value2
                WHEN Value2 < Value1 THEN Value3
                 WHEN Value2 > Value1 THEN Value4
          END AS Final_Value
   )
   select * from CTE
   where  Final_Value <> 0 
          and Final_Value is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's not possible to filter in the where clause, so there is a simple solution i use in some cases, with a subselect.

Example:

```
select X.* from (
SELECT 
     ACCGRPID, 
     LOCID, 
     USERID4, 
     LOBNAME, 
     REINSTYPE, 
     INCEPTDATE, 
     EXPIREDATE, 
     Latitude, 
     Longitude, 
     CountryRMSCode, 
     StreetAddress, 
     CityName, 
     ACCGRPNUM, 
     ACCGRPNAME,
     CASE
        WHEN Value = 0 THEN Value2
        WHEN Value2 < Value1 THEN Value3
        WHEN Value2 > Value1 THEN Value4
     END AS Final_Value
    from <table_name>) X
where X.Final_Value != 0 and X.Final_Value is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Review the CASE WHEN so it won't result in 0 or NULL

For example:

```
CASE
WHEN Value = 0 THEN Value2
WHEN Value2 <= Value1 THEN Value3
WHEN Value2 > Value1 THEN Value4
ELSE Value2
END AS Final_Value
```

Of course, this one assumes that Value2, Value3 and Value4 are NOT NULL and not 0.